# Problem with constants in Solving first order differential equation with perturbation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, constants

> $$y'+\lambda \ y^4 +y=0$$
>   Where $\lambda$ is very small and $y(1)=-0.5$.

I've tried to solve it by  Substituting: $y=y_0+\lambda y_1 +\lambda^2 y_2+\cdots$

but I had problems with the integration constants that appeared  after solving the other partial differential equation when substituting: $y=y_0+\lambda y_1 +\lambda^2 y_2+\cdots$ in the main equation.

Comment: Could you add your calculation attempt? It might help to spot mistakes or missing steps.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve it directly by rearrangement. You need to evaluate the integral $\int_1^y \frac{dz}{\lambda z^4+z}$. Notice that:

$$\frac{1}{\lambda z^4+z}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{\lambda z^2}{1+\lambda z^3},$$

which you hopefully know how to integrate.

Comment: While correct, presumably the OP wants a perturbation-theoretic solution instead.